# separate user@domain.com from user@example.com

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I've a Postfix + Dovecot server in my Arch-based distro. There are multiple domains pointing to my host and multiple users in it. The issue here is that, mails to user@domain.com also appear in user@example.com. But I want that addresses not present in /etc/postfix/virtual get rejected. This is how it looks.

```
eumela.ga eumela.ga
# megver83@eumela.ga megver83@localhost
eum@eumela.ga eum@localhost

megver83.ga megver83.ga
megver83@megver83.ga megver83@localhost
```

However, I'm able to send messages to eum@megver83.ga, instead of getting rejected. And even users that don't appear there work. Is it an problem of main.cf or master.cf? Here they're:

master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=eumela.ga
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

`postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/bin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 134217728
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 134217728
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, localhost.megver83.ga, megver83.ga
mydomain = eumela.ga
myhostname = pi.megver83.ga
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
relay_domains = *
relayhost =
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients, permit_mynetworks, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/imap.megver83.ga/fullchain.pem # These certs are multi-domain, although it doesn't matter
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/imap.megver83.ga/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I've tried all of what appears [here](https://bpaste.net/raw/32d77c58d183) with no success :-(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: Google something for "postfix forward rewrite" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `megver83.ga` in `mydestination`, which means it'll be treated as a local domain (delivery to local system users, etc etc), not a virtual domain.

Comment: yes, removing it and using the virtual_alias_domains parameter worked for me